# Query and Extract only ID number for Flask reply

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, Threads for threads and Posts for replies.

I am trying to grab an ID of a Thread so I can store the reply with the right ID in the posts table.

```
thread_ID = Threads.query.get_or_404(id)
print(thread_ID)
```

the above will print  `<Thread 1>` and it is of type `<class '__main__.Threads'>`

In my reply function I have currently hard coded the number 1 `thread_id = 1` so I can only reply to Threads with the ID 1.

```
@app.route('/reply/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])       
def reply(id):
    thread = Threads.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        threadid = Threads.query.get(id)
        print(type(threadid))
        #post username
        post_name = request.form['reply_username']
        #threadID
        thread_id = 1
        #content
        post_content = request.form['reply_content']
        if post_content != '' :
            if post_name == '':
                
                #add both
                new_post = Posts(content=post_content,thread_id=thread_id,)
                try:
                    # add content and title to DB
                    db.session.add(new_post)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect('/')
                except:
                    return 'Post could not be added'
            else:
                new_post = Posts(content=post_content,username=post_name,thread_id=thread_id)
                try:
                    # add content and title to DB
                    db.session.add(new_post)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect('/')
                except:
                    return 'Post could not be added'
    
    return render_template('reply.html', allposts=allposts, thread=thread)
```

I checked and `thread_ID = Threads.query.get_or_404(id)` will always contain the right number but there is a `" <Thread * > "` wrapped around it, but I only need the number as INT.

I tried converting the variable `thread_ID` to a string and then extracting the Int with regex but I cant get it done, it always ends up being an empty list.

Any advice how I can only get the number out?

Is there something I can add to the query to not return the `<Thread >` and only return the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `thread_id = id`. No regex etc needed. I was blind sighted and dint realize that `<int:id>` is already passing the `id` that only contains the `INT`.